# Why ExecuteNonQuery() is not working?

Tags: c#

```
SqlCommand cmd1=new SqlCommand(query);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I execute the code it says that the connection is not initialized. Then, I change the code for:

```
cmd1.ExecuteNonQyery(conn);
```

And this is marked as an error.  I then make `conn.Open()` and then it says the connection is not initialized.  What should I do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you connected to the db already when you try to run this?

Comment: When you run in to a problem like this, you should read the documentation and find out how the class is supposed to be used.

Comment: Are you really trying to call `ExecuteNonQyery`? Note the last part should be `Query` rather than `Qyery`.

Comment: This is just a nitpick, but why call your variable `query` if it's not a query?

Comment: I have a query and that's ok and yeah I have done the inizialization of the connection and I have tried and insertion before and everything worked just fine I don't know why I get this error now

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the command's connection property.

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query);
cmd1.Connection = conn;
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error messages are trying to tell you, you need to set the command's connection:

```
cmd1.Connection = something;
```

You should also dispose both the connection and the command using the `using` statment.

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell your `SqlCommand` about the `SqlConnection`

i.e. try this

```
   SqlCommand cmd1=new SqlCommand(query,conn);
   cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```